# How to Sort data generated from JQuery Handlebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, handlebars.js

I have data dynamically generated from handlebar.js . Data is populates in div's inside div's. I want to sort that data based on different attributes which are generated by handlebar.

I want to sort on the basis of Name, ComputerCode, Fathers Name etc
Here is the Code 
`
            
            
            
            
                {{#each LawyerList}}

```
        <li id="Record" style="padding-left: 0px;" class="col-lg-12 col-md-7 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <div class="list-unstyled">
            <div class="row no-margin">
            <div style="width: 90px;" class="no-padding shadow-10 pull-left">
            <div class="crop">
            <span class="helper">
            </span>
            <img src="/Content/images/nopic.jpg" style="width: 85%;" >

            </div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right:0; margin-left:90px; min-height: 90px;">
            <a href="/profile/53f45c88dabfaedf43621afb" target="_blank" class="un-styled">
            <h6 class="people-result-name">
                <strong id="name" style="margin-right:5px" class="ng-binding">{{Name}} S/O {{FatherName}} </strong>
            </h6>
            </a>
            <p style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;" class="font-xs">
            <strong class="text-danger">Office Contact: &nbsp;</strong>
            <span class="ng-binding">{{OfficeContact}}</span>
            <span class="color-grey">&nbsp; | &nbsp;</span>
            <strong class="text-danger">Cell No: &nbsp;</strong>
            <span class="ng-binding">{{CellNo}}</span>
            <span class="color-grey">&nbsp; | &nbsp;</span>
            <strong class="text-danger">Computer Code : &nbsp;</strong>
            <span class="ng-binding">{{ComputerCode}}</span>
            </p>
            <div style="min-height: 20px;" class="list-unstyled">
            <div ng-if="!result.contact.affiliation &amp;&amp; result.org" class="ng-scope">
            <div class="font-xs ng-binding">
            {{OfficeAddress}}
            </div>
            </div>

            <div ng-show="result.homepage" class="ng-hide">
            <div class="font-xs">

            <a href="" class="linked ng-binding"></a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="tag in result.tags" class="btn-u btn-brd rounded btn-u-default btn-xs btn-interest ng-scope">
            <a href="/search/K-Feldspar" style="color: gray;" class="font-xs ng-binding">Civil</a>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="tag in result.tags" class="btn-u btn-brd rounded btn-u-default btn-xs btn-interest ng-scope">
            <a href="/search/Dates" style="color: gray;" class="font-xs ng-binding">Family</a>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="tag in result.tags" class="btn-u btn-brd rounded btn-u-default btn-xs btn-interest ng-scope">
            <a href="/search/Miocene" style="color: gray;" class="font-xs ng-binding">Corporate</a>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="tag in result.tags" class="btn-u btn-brd rounded btn-u-default btn-xs btn-interest ng-scope">
            <a href="/search/Paleoelevation" style="color: gray;" class="font-xs ng-binding">Criminal</a>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="tag in result.tags" class="btn-u btn-brd rounded btn-u-default btn-xs btn-interest ng-scope">
            <a href="/search/Stable Isotopes" style="color: gray;" class="font-xs ng-binding">Terrorist</a>
            </div>
            </div><div style="padding-right:0; padding-left:110px"><hr style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px"></div></div></div>
        </div><!---End of col-lg-12 col-md-7 col-xs-12 no-padding--->
            {{/each}}
        </li>
            <!---End of Record--->
            </script>
    </ul>
            </div>
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can sort the result (returned from ajax) using jQuery function sort(). 
For Example:

```
var homes = [
    {
        "h_id": "3",
        "city": "Dallas",
        "state": "TX",
        "zip": "75201",
        "price": "162500"
    }, {
        "h_id": "4",
        "city": "Bevery Hills",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "90210",
        "price": "319250"
    }, {
        "h_id": "5",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "zip": "00010",
        "price": "962500"
    }];
homes.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price) } );
```